# Properties of alternating p-series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $p>1$

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p}=(1-2^{1-p})\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$$

I  wrote the series in the form: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p}=-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n)^p})$$ to see if i can derive the result exploiting the convergence of the series.

But it did not do so much.

Can someone help me to solve this by giving me a hint or a partial solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p}&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}-\frac{1}{(2n)^p})\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^p}+\frac{1}{(2n)^p}\right)-2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(2n)^p}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1}\frac{1}{n^p}-2^{1-p}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^p}
\end{eqnarray}
and letting $N\to\infty$, you will get the answer.